# "Fold" the array

Tags: code-golf, array

An example will easily explain this to you. Suppose an array `[1,2,3,4,5]`

**Step 1**

```
1 2 3 4 5
----+----
```

**Step 2**

```
       5/
      4/
1 2 3 /
----+/
```

**Step 3**

```
    5|
    4|
1 2 3|
----+|
```

**Step 4**

```
  5\
   4\
1 2 3\
----+-\
```

**Step 5** Take the sum of face-to-face elements

```
6 6 3
```

You just successfully folded an array 1 time. 2 times folding means to fold `6 6 3` again.

**Challenge**

Given an array of positive integers, return it folded like above. Traling whitespace accepted in output.

**Test cases** (Randomly generated 100):

```
[98, 82, 25, 51, 20] -> [118, 133, 25]
[52, 75, 89, 96, 82] -> [134, 171, 89]
[53, 12, 70, 10, 19, 36] -> [89, 31, 80]
[63, 43, 89, 74, 31] -> [94, 117, 89]
[98, 52, 67, 66, 78, 92, 51, 87, 1, 7] -> [105, 53, 154, 117, 170]
[55, 7, 30, 80] -> [135, 37]
[77, 69, 57, 29, 76, 65, 62, 71, 58] -> [135, 140, 119, 94, 76]
[79, 84, 57, 47, 99] -> [178, 131, 57]
[81, 95, 54, 52, 6, 33, 85, 36, 93] -> [174, 131, 139, 85, 6]
[2, 41, 33, 90] -> [92, 74]
[84, 84, 20, 39] -> [123, 104]
[78, 34, 40, 19, 86, 92, 4, 11, 12, 86] -> [164, 46, 51, 23, 178]
[20, 19, 82, 75, 1] -> [21, 94, 82]
[18, 82, 22, 19, 61, 57, 66, 32, 1] -> [19, 114, 88, 76, 61]
[11, 95, 12, 48, 75, 47, 73] -> [84, 142, 87, 48]
[41, 11, 69, 9, 44, 10, 98, 13] -> [54, 109, 79, 53]
[4, 17, 38, 51] -> [55, 55]
[61, 27, 46, 81, 32, 41, 78, 45, 21, 13] -> [74, 48, 91, 159, 73]
[26, 28, 36, 95, 37, 65, 48, 14, 42] -> [68, 42, 84, 160, 37]
[73, 47, 38, 57, 78, 97, 38, 43, 4, 37] -> [110, 51, 81, 95, 175]
[91, 33, 72, 45, 45] -> [136, 78, 72]
[83, 72, 15, 74, 4] -> [87, 146, 15]
[25, 72, 35, 26] -> [51, 107]
[4, 38, 56, 35, 86, 69, 8, 97, 26] -> [30, 135, 64, 104, 86]
[13, 19, 80, 90] -> [103, 99]
[90, 38, 32, 14] -> [104, 70]
[47, 70, 5, 69, 72, 90, 22, 51] -> [98, 92, 95, 141]
[98, 68, 6, 49, 94, 95, 50, 57, 3, 46] -> [144, 71, 63, 99, 189]
[15, 56, 5, 71, 1, 57] -> [72, 57, 76]
[51, 27, 18, 29, 13, 22, 77, 45] -> [96, 104, 40, 42]
[1, 92, 25, 34] -> [35, 117]
[90, 72, 17, 62, 44, 15, 80, 61] -> [151, 152, 32, 106]
[73, 95, 46, 50, 9, 27, 31, 84, 37] -> [110, 179, 77, 77, 9]
[38, 31, 78, 37, 49, 56, 27] -> [65, 87, 127, 37]
[27, 6, 92, 39, 89, 81, 27] -> [54, 87, 181, 39]
[77, 10, 81, 53] -> [130, 91]
[77, 6, 38, 42, 3, 5, 42, 29, 55, 22] -> [99, 61, 67, 84, 8]
[18, 42, 93, 81, 31, 31, 50, 21] -> [39, 92, 124, 112]
[89, 100, 91, 80, 24, 90, 48, 73, 44] -> [133, 173, 139, 170, 24]
[14, 14, 73, 86, 18, 57, 53, 63, 27] -> [41, 77, 126, 143, 18]
[61, 21, 21, 72] -> [133, 42]
[91, 94, 57, 7, 54, 45, 6, 20, 44, 82] -> [173, 138, 77, 13, 99]
[50, 91, 21, 22, 82, 15] -> [65, 173, 43]
[26, 64, 72, 82, 16, 21, 99, 99, 64, 39] -> [65, 128, 171, 181, 37]
[84, 47, 17, 68, 22, 97, 43, 46, 96] -> [180, 93, 60, 165, 22]
[60, 46, 97, 50, 7] -> [67, 96, 97]
[77, 52, 56, 11, 73, 76] -> [153, 125, 67]
[71, 31, 73, 90, 93, 8, 21, 63, 73, 29] -> [100, 104, 136, 111, 101]
[81, 67, 39, 39, 72, 56, 14] -> [95, 123, 111, 39]
[93, 44, 86, 26, 96, 49, 3, 88, 96, 100] -> [193, 140, 174, 29, 145]
[85, 93, 55, 65, 17, 97, 56, 3] -> [88, 149, 152, 82]
[99, 4, 91, 80, 27, 60, 77, 100, 56, 31] -> [130, 60, 191, 157, 87]
[41, 64, 91, 55, 15, 43] -> [84, 79, 146]
[11, 56, 68, 85, 29, 74, 5, 85, 99, 4] -> [15, 155, 153, 90, 103]
[86, 10, 17, 43] -> [129, 27]
[45, 75, 55, 74, 1, 84, 54, 37, 54, 88] -> [133, 129, 92, 128, 85]
[65, 96, 78, 94] -> [159, 174]
[36, 36, 47, 78] -> [114, 83]
[44, 32, 88, 58, 51] -> [95, 90, 88]
[77, 60, 44, 17, 60] -> [137, 77, 44]
[6, 76, 2, 32] -> [38, 78]
[58, 48, 19, 69, 57, 46, 74, 97] -> [155, 122, 65, 126]
[77, 100, 2, 12, 16, 57] -> [134, 116, 14]
[71, 9, 98, 50, 86, 98, 36, 21, 76, 33] -> [104, 85, 119, 86, 184]
[53, 11, 66, 36, 53, 21, 15, 8, 14, 54] -> [107, 25, 74, 51, 74]
[58, 44, 52, 68, 24] -> [82, 112, 52]
[80, 78, 57, 28, 78] -> [158, 106, 57]
[89, 72, 26, 57] -> [146, 98]
[1, 71, 68, 96] -> [97, 139]
[67, 70, 24, 65, 4, 82] -> [149, 74, 89]
[39, 62, 77, 35, 7, 14] -> [53, 69, 112]
[77, 90, 89, 41, 28, 23, 14, 18, 84] -> [161, 108, 103, 64, 28]
[11, 13, 92, 97] -> [108, 105]
[60, 82, 63, 76] -> [136, 145]
[3, 17, 46, 33, 91, 54, 88] -> [91, 71, 137, 33]
[11, 9, 51, 69] -> [80, 60]
[33, 85, 28, 6] -> [39, 113]
[23, 89, 21, 13, 98, 21, 66, 37] -> [60, 155, 42, 111]
[10, 38, 53, 35, 26, 11, 2, 47] -> [57, 40, 64, 61]
[66, 77, 5, 84] -> [150, 82]
[74, 43, 49, 65, 6] -> [80, 108, 49]
[86, 29, 60, 100, 3, 66, 86, 96] -> [182, 115, 126, 103]
[65, 4, 74, 67, 9, 35, 14, 70, 2, 91] -> [156, 6, 144, 81, 44]
[52, 2, 99, 49] -> [101, 101]
[18, 54, 59, 84, 9, 8, 14, 49, 22, 90] -> [108, 76, 108, 98, 17]
[94, 64, 52, 56, 73] -> [167, 120, 52]
[6, 59, 56, 47, 9, 88, 86] -> [92, 147, 65, 47]
[11, 26, 26, 44, 29, 38, 92, 74, 83, 1] -> [12, 109, 100, 136, 67]
[42, 70, 26, 11, 57] -> [99, 81, 26]
[38, 12, 26, 91, 79, 42] -> [80, 91, 117]
[22, 58, 21, 1, 49, 10, 60, 60, 90] -> [112, 118, 81, 11, 49]
[72, 92, 97, 57, 4, 86, 35, 20] -> [92, 127, 183, 61]
[79, 59, 67, 86] -> [165, 126]
[66, 82, 61, 42, 1, 25, 37, 91] -> [157, 119, 86, 43]
[14, 23, 34, 69, 22, 41, 81, 43, 28] -> [42, 66, 115, 110, 22]
[59, 54, 63, 43, 55, 46] -> [105, 109, 106]
[42, 12, 90, 18, 72, 73, 6] -> [48, 85, 162, 18]
[94, 1, 38, 20, 66, 25] -> [119, 67, 58]
[41, 20, 67, 63, 16, 41, 17, 86] -> [127, 37, 108, 79]
[91, 22, 48, 11] -> [102, 70]
```

Comment: [Welcome to PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange)! This was a nice first challenge, but sadly we already had the exact same before, which is why I closed it as a duplicate. For future challenges it is recommended to first post them in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) where other users can give feedback and find potential duplicates before getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 5 bytes (Pointed by Kevin Cruijsen)

```
2ä`R+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6PCShCDt//@jDXWMdIx1THRMYwE)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
2ä`R0ª+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6PCShCCDQ6u0//@PNtQx0jHWMdExjQUA)

Trivial solution

```
2ä      # Halve [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
`       # Unpack [1,2,3],[4,5]
R       # Reverse [1,2,3],[5,4]
0ª      # Fill [1,2,3],[5,4,0]
+       # Add [6,6,3]
```

Comment: If you switch to the legacy version of 05AB1E the `0ª` isn't necessary: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6PCShCDt//@jDXWMdIx1THRMYwE).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes

```javascript
f=([n,...a])=>n?[n+~~a.pop(),...f(a)]:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBRD4IgEAfw9z4Fj7AIQRSkzfogjgdm2moNXLUe/ep2l@slKzd3E28//nfn8Ai39noa7puYDt009TVtIhdCBM/qXdw3cT2OQQxpoAyPexqY34apTfGWLp24pCPtaeMqTqqck7zkpFRQpWeMLJ8sI41S0Ky0xm6/@oBKQCwglePEGUT/QLoAyCrsXkLgK8QkVHwB1GaJIYSXaWTkgjHAFHrOYwts@53HYRxlv8bBBeFsBn4bmMvCt8vnZVVwBsWi/JpL4hYxf/kWlZV@egI)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = ([           // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,             //   n = next integer
  ...a           //   a[] = array of remaining integers
]) =>            //
  n ?            // if n is defined:
    [ n +        //   append the sum of n
      ~~a.pop(), //   and the last element extracted from a[],
                 //   coerced to 0 if it doesn't exist
      ...f(a)    //   append the result of a recursive call
    ]            //
  :              // else:
    a            //   return a[], which is now guaranteed to be
                 //   an empty array
```

Comment: How did you post after the question got closed? (BTW nice solution)

Comment: @auser I didn't notice the challenge was closed when I answered it, but I think this happens every now and then if the page was loaded when the challenge was still open. (Which makes me wonder how SE handles that on the server side, but anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>104</s> 102 bytes

```java
i->{int l=i.length,o=l/2+l%2,j=0,r[]=new int[o];for(;j<o;j++)r[j]=i[j]+(j<l-j-1?i[l-j-1]:0);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLJbsIwEEDvfMVcKiXChH0NaVX1xKEnjlEOJphg19jIdqgQyrfTCRCWwkjJRJM3@wi6ow2x/DmmkloL35QrONRqgNJsQrqmKmN0IRlw5ZhZ0ZSd/m0N31F3Z4UZusFF0Bon4Jh14J2/udrmzg9PRHEOv80XkqdgHXWodpovYVNm9@bOcJWhEzWZ9atqLhVZ5vLt1TADq2XuuFYQXY03OtNyxZaQ6iU78sb7AWsBGfFAMpW5NdGRbHbq8q1DRNQiJk4ixX5PxeskXGnjhWKqQ1Gv@yYWScTxVffEVDZEo/3B45NOJi0/NFiUUWDC4hjWHqdwmcMXtcxCdDejSg7jEYFRh0CnT6DfRt0qyDPVR2KIxGhMYDwoPV5SXQLtkmyhLh@ku4NX5ADJXvccb9hDql1coeKuCRxDtcOqj8mtI/9fQ/O9dWwT6NwFeCHKSeU9pS5F4NUFuDcZfBpD9zZw@rx1r9pnUObwqkS@/xDmckh3x1TUiuMf)

Comment: Java feels very symbolic :-)

Comment: What do you mean? :'D

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZJLj4IwEIDv/oo5Qiz4fiK72ezJw572aDhUrNhubU1b3BjDb3cHBR@rk8CQ4Zv3CLqngVj9nFJJrYUvyhUcGw1AabUg3VCVMbqUDLhyzKxpys7/dobvqbuzwhzdoBK0LhJwzDrwLt9c7XLnR2eiuITf5UvJU7COOlR7zVewLbN7385wlaETNZn162qqiixz@e5qmIPVMndcK4ivxhudablmK0j1ip148HbEWkDGPJRMZW5DdCwD2eoSEbeJWSSxYr/n0nUSrbXxIjHTkW8WIok5vpqemMmg2RTvfCEDkUzbfmSwGqPARMUpajy2Xw3gk1pmIb4bTi3HyZjAuEugOyAw6KBuF@SZGiAxQmI8ITAZlh4vqR6BTkm2UZcP0r3hK3KIZL93iTfqI9UprlBx1wROoF5e3cf01pH/r6Hvg3VsG@rchXgayknlPaUuReC5hbgwGX4YQw82dPqybq9eZFjm8OpEvv8QprqguysqGsXpDw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:a[1:]and[a[0]+a[-1]]+f(a[1:-1])or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVjLbhw3ELzrK@ZmCZYDNt80oPzIYg8b2IIFyLLgyAny9Qqrujg7CZCNdmeaZD@qqpt@/eft24@X9P7@@PB8@f7Hl8t2@Xw52efz5eXL6XIK54@X0yc7nz8@3uLx/Hr34@d2ef/729Pz180@32zb08vr/fbj19v2sH2/vN5@/evyfI@Hv95u73778/X56e32w/bp9@3D3d20fv359PJ2@3g7De62hwcsvHs/jX6/9Xi/xXK/FZt/wxlLTmbzhaWEN@ebU5kmbZr0cb@NiiUyS3maNcMbmE17g2mYf/GZ5qm6KZYmGIZpWKdhTr5fy3jhRgPbWdN2cA4n1/mgzlPb/D2iO9rns/mnyY8A/3F6WTtYw0FlPp8/UuDB8nk@S22@bNh3elDm3whP5hl1vqwIYW5e@mGFZQSEiOBkq1g/f/Ts6/P8jCH7xuRhBxzT55cB/7LCmccjdrgxv4@0VmWtsjT8NQ6ZC7L5iqEIkIOWsXN2B@J0La3DI9IQ8BpuoEBZpejV88cUeaW6qmMVdlUgwA6t4/C1UvVXmaJ5FiYMbk62IBTdtppnBBVLcV@DV2ZY1JVpw2LlBr7k7ocglU1JQXSWo9c7wyUkA6tQuPlfzg61wZT7ImIgoKAobsIiBDTdAaDkD5BRgG34G5tHj1IlZRzZy9Mo2nVnlAhuDjwrg37OLM2VsauaBJfjCJaIOIstFTtGL5nVsFCYPGQ614Ry/QZHMu3EyiD0r7Q1RDCEjxbd41wWbkWahjp1WVhxzmVlGFxB7IatoAMwAuKjsIEDLTRPI72sbgA8oQxyeNmDbKRMZR0yUTZLnYSlcEWyhUTazBiC703E5PUWTAONCQnE7gfCQyyI8VrPIXFgWrJJPpDy6WUWbUnD4HlGahf6gSIwvtKduQH1B5lCrMVfOp8dB1G1QmBFAAIRICMIFJ5BXlYpIJoMB1zMpI27i4QnxUuZsaZssFbN1YgoL567ugjFukBQmLNQhSXESCYHEgSeUXf/jyMDO@AjPgiX6RfwAWEkDeFHrQKkiRZuCTfxRZpCyRqOzLUAPOQC0mpIcXE2HpSle8DLsKXHAn5kgYp/Q1bB1ygiDckMGgM1UDIE25FEY32QhqiUwUk4a5ESSFagYCE4pZFevEL6qUbAyAJjoiomybM12uLg7CzHKzDCxGO0I@BpZYOawvTBCMy2vuRHnxYPZxElQ0pLsHkLAcOra37Oh1bsrnUdsnhVFBqPiK7UVq4F5bK8VAyMbcuq@iokmwnP1ybDlZA89n6vb1NDyk247X4ipIE6BqQswlEEkCAAsXppZy6CzJrXbQGv@dQxVtMG6IFM9AH439a2PoAgQTQVBMgKHdg9KBQGj@PqmiGIoBRNY38Mpu4NB1D0JO3h2cKFd6@kNUT5SCoNMljdd5ApefNzLVgKCGOfLSDK1I8MJUb/xzvg3gulvIAhkm72lyEVYDNGofIBzM1T7LwLWm0H4rEA3s5ApqYOW7UJTofw5EM/bvSxqntjR5Qa/kaNc8V/0plVGezD/6kYU/oRZdWk2K5nWKRswZPiE0FRy5KMlewCRX3pR3rGneD0CJAqnnB21d0ZEhjkRbHxYYNZW3FK4diQXVyR6HKYHVBzxND7Ui2Rkbjf50xpa8ZB1YceqrXEqPPISdGuUWFcx1GwABGPpdjMHejk1Ku7mAZuaiLsalA@mJvj1JkwfEgCrzgIamCh7nAkPTTdXjTruqDlNdubxrrq8sbRqJBUxrqsLZo3NmLBNKwyzDUCd4qnQypSi/ECgAheK87k/VAULJ9Nbs3UYmI8xkzp6N5b2c37VXEGRRHsrJolIPSc0g4amgVgtn@wvaqPJ79HLNJT28fqIWygwfsfyAO/qQjZu0FfealUFQaSnGOxi0YU7HgouJsVqSKSVI9KR5WiUCSxR9cKsvZAjKFkEI4prZnbC1Mlf5wrMGitiwlCqNemacYOoRtbXP4uMa3X0YJ6UtS3pyTiPI12SJrPlY4kzDVrUmg@GSElvBfwutdcSXbWBokcp9fkmsr72jUIpi0PKQvkgA6BJckd7f9pQ3SyrKZMSRImcAgbjzvNDu9cG/sAVtmJOT2iTZDogHeU9u3NZe8mHA5AAl0dx04eBMN2GQ4AaFUh8XrDyTB7llYLXBclqxwtgmhU/YgiaRuuYeu2R4nM65bShImodpXVh5ImahIiXS9yUbcr75kAIrtt1sV/lXfRcqypsGrGNPGWyBzX61HXqOIjMGd7Acw8PaZ@VY83CLpDluliyOrzhqDhg@DywhN@h1u0@dyehDreF4fmyv1mvAsu4RN99CS8Nb63IybaQTk5V6G4YA4UuarIWXc4oDiKqNix1oVHC5qJWMbs7M@aB/Z7C/7ZQ7WoKoHpbmTdFRJTjsyz2rRB1Th8Dm@qqAqgg@PjujyaElHWrZsWzT1BZ@FN/JgpvxcIsW1ofI262ttKUSBQzv8C)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒHUÐeS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJI/QwxNSg////x9taaGjYGGko2BkqqNgagikDWIB)

```python
        # implicit input                            [98, 82, 25, 51, 20]
ŒH      # split input list into two halves          [[98, 82, 25], [51, 20]]
   Ðe   # apply at even indices (the second half):                 ^^^^^^^^
  U     #   reverse the list                        [[98, 82, 25], [20, 51]]
     S  # take the sum of the lists                 [98+20, 82+51, 25+0]
        # implicit output                           [118, 133, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 53 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.splice(0,a.length/2).map(j=>j+a.pop()).concat(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcaxDgIhDADQ32ljrXpq4sJ9gIMOjsahIYAQhOYgl/j16JteklWaXaL27XoZ3gwxs3DTHK2DPQlnV0J/7ybkjygkM6eNsFYFRLa1WOkgOP5rNTvONcD1cb9x60ssIfoveHgeaKIjnej8QsTxAw)

```javascript
a.splice(0,a.length/2)     // Slice first half
.map(j=>j+a.pop())         // Add from tails
.concat(a)                 // For the pop and splice only middle remains
```